# How to figure out contribution of multipliers

Tags: polynomials

Hope I can explain this properly.

Suppose we have formula

$$
T = (a_1 + a_2)\cdot m_1\cdot m_2
$$

I'm trying to find how much $m_1$ and $m_2$ contribute to $T$.

I did as follows:

Set $$S = a_1 + a_2$$

Then $m1$ contributes $\frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2}$

$m_2$ contributes $\frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}$

$a_1$ contributes $a_1$

$a_2$ contributes $a_2$

Is there better method ?  The contribution of $m_1$ should not be affected by it coming before $m_2$.  And $a_1$ and $a_2$ should always contribute themselves.

I feel $\log$ should be used.

Comment: i'm not entirely sure what you mean by "contribute". Contribute in what way?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out.  Is there a standard definition of contribute for these type of functions ?

Comment: No, I mean, why do you want the contribution in the first place? What are you trying to measurE?

Comment: I would guess a partial derivative (with respect to $m_1$, $m_2$, etc.) is what you want.

Comment: I'm trying to come up with answer of what I'm trying to measure for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for are partial derivatives.
If you think of $T$ as a function of $m_1$ and $m_2$, i.e. $T=f(m_1,m_2)=S \times m_1 \times m_2$ (where $S=(a_1+a_2)$ is a constant term) then
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial m_1}=S\times m_2
$$
and

$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial m_2}=S\times m_1
$$

and you interpret them as usual, i.e. an increase in $m_1$ by 1 unit (whatever the units are), increases the $T$ by $S\times m_2$ units.

That would be a way of interpreting multipliers (but as per comments above, neither of use is sure what you're trying to measure).